# media="screen, projection" - что это?

Tags: css

Знаю `media="print"` - версия CSS для печати, но `media="screen, projection"` не знаю. Прошу как можно подробнее рассказать про него.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очевидно, [проектор](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80) ;)

А вот [здесь](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html) пишут:

> **projection**
>
> Intended for projected presentations,
> for example projectors. Please consult
> the section on paged media for
> information about formatting issues
> that are specific to paged media.

Что по-русски приблизительно:

> Проекционные презентации, например, проекторы. См. секцию paged носителей (те же принтеры и прочее).

Comment: Что за проектор?

Comment: ну как... http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80

а вот здесь http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html

пишут:

**projection**

Intended for projected presentations, for example projectors. Please consult the section on paged media for information about formatting issues that are specific to paged media.

что по-русски приблизительно:

Проекционные презентации, например проекторы. См. секцию paged носителей (те же принтеры и прочее...)

Answer (score 1):

Не проще покопаться по справочной литературе?:) **"projection"** - проектор, а **"screen"** - экран монитора.
*[Описание атрибута на htmlbook.ru](http://htmlbook.ru/css/media)*

> Что за проектор?

**Проектор** - средство вывода информации на плоскость (в наше время стоит почти во всех школах).